# keyboard Module

Tags: python, keyboard, passwords

I am a beginner in Python and I recently learnt about the 'keyboard' module. I tried to use it to take password , i.e., as I type alphabets, the characters are added into the variable one by one. But I do not want the letters to echo again. How do I do that?

```
import keyboard, sys
pw=''
def op(s):
    global pw
    if s=='back': pw=pw[:-1]
    else: 
        pw+=s
        sys.stdout.write('*')

def esc():
    keyboard.unhook_all_hotkeys


for i in 'qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm':
    exec('keyboard.add_hotkey("{0}",lambda: op("{0}"))'.format(i))
keyboard.add_hotkey('backspace',lambda: op('back'))
keyboard.add_hotkey('enter',lambda: esc)
print('Enter Password: ',end='')
i=0
while True:
    if i==0:
        i=1
    if keyboard.is_pressed('enter') == True : break
```

Please help with the same using keyboard module only. I am hoping to use the same  technique used here in other programs. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you need to use the keyboard module? What you need can easily be achieved using the [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html) module

Comment: Yes. I do not want to use getpass module. Thanks for the suggestion. But, I am trying to do it using keyboard module only